# LOAD Data text fields vs numeric comma interactions

Tags: mysql, number-formatting, bulk-load

I'm using the following to load a csv file to a mysql database:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_location.csv' 
INTO TABLE social_spend 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

I have a text field that is written as: `'D,i,Y'`, which, after being uploaded shows in my database as the same:`'D,i,Y'`

I have a numeric field that is written as: `'1,234'` that is automatically trunacted on upload to: `'1'`

Why are text field commas preserved, but numeric fields are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL encounters a text string in a numeric context, it coerces it to a number. Sloppily.

So if you use the string `00134abc` in a numeric context, you get the number `134`. And, in your case it sees `1,234` and coerces it to `1`.

Yeah, we all know about this being a pain in the xxx neck.

You may be able to do your load with something like this (NOT debugged!)

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_location.csv' 
INTO TABLE social_spend 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(col1, col2, @yourNumber, col4)
SET numberColumn = CAST(REPLACE(@yourNumber, ',', '') AS SIGNED INTEGER);
```

Between the parentheses you can list columns of your table to correspond to columns in your CSV. If you put `@something` you can use it in an expression in a SET clause. The expression I showed strips out the commas from your numbers.